# Writing a small Java code that can take 3 integers, and output the smallest one

Tags: java

I am in the beginnings of learning Java, and have an assignment that is providing me with some difficulty (which I presume is not actually difficult).

The instructions are as follows:

"Within a class called MathCalculations, write a method named findMin that accepts three integers as parameters and returns the smallest of the three values. For example, the call findMin(1,10,-1) would return -1. You must use the Math class min function (which only takes 2 parameters).  Write a main method in the class that calls findMin(5, 7, 3) and prints the returned result (see below for format)."

As the prompt states, I have to use the Math.min function, yet it only takes two parameters.  I wrote the code below that gives me the desired output for the assignment, but I do not believe I have done it in the correct way.  I am having trouble understanding what is meant by "write a method named findMin that accepts three integers as parameters."  Can anyone offer me some help?  Thanks in advance.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    findMin(3);
}       
public static int findMin(int min) {
    int minimum = Math.min(5, 7);
    int minimum2 = Math.min(minimum, 3);
        System.out.println("The minimum of 5, 7, and 3 is " + minimum2);
        return minimum2;
  }
}
```

Comment: "_write a method named findMin that accepts three integers as parameters_" Why does yours only accept one?

Comment: You teacher wants you to write a methods that has a name like `public int findMin(int a, int b, int c)` that returns the smallest of a, b, and c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

A method that accepts 3 (integer) parameters would look like this ...

```
public static int findMin(int p1, int p2, int p3) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're about 99% of the way there, the only problem you have is the fact that `findMin` should take three parameters, not one.

`findMin` should look more like...

```
public static int findMin(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
```

Then, instead of using `5`, `7`, and `3` directly, you would use `num1`, `num2`, `num3` in there place.

Then you would call the method using something like...

```
int min = findMin(5, 7, 3);
```

Don't forget to assign the resulting value from the method call ;)

You may find [Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) of some help

Comment: @StephenC That's the first time I've being told that - or do you mean because this is "home work"?

Comment: Yes ... obviously.  But I'm probably wasting my breath 'cos lots of others have given him a *complete* solution ...

Comment: @StephenC Apart from "how to call the method", not sure it presents much more information than your own answer ... but that's my opinion (no offense)

Comment: @StephenC *"lots of others have given him a complete solution"* That's what I was trying to avoid while giving enough to lead them forward. I appreciate your point of view though and agree dumping code on unexpecting posters does little to help them in the long run...

Comment: Big thanks to all of you guys.  I realize there was some hazy bit about giving me the answer, or too much info, but luckily as soon as I realized how to give 3 values to the parameter, it took off from there.  Big thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you allow the user to only specify 1 parameter while the requirement is 3, after which you hardcode two others yourself.

A simple solution could be this:

```
private static int findMin(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    int low = arg0;
    low = Math.min(low, arg1);
    low = Math.min(low, arg2);

    return low;
}
```

- Assign the first parameter to the variable 'low'
- Keep comparing this variable to the other parameters and assign the result of it to `low`

Answer (score 0):

You could also put the ints into an array and sort it. The first element will be the smallest, therfore the minimum.

```
public static int findMin(int int1, int int2, int int3) {
    int[] nums={int1, int2, int3};
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    return nums[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just use composition:

```
public static int findMin(int a, int b, int c) {
    return Math.min(Math.min(a, b), c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Coral language
Function LargestNumber(integer num1,integer num2,integer num3) returns integer largestNum
// LargestNumber function definition with 3 parameters

// check if num3 is largest

if num3 > num1 and num3 > num2

```
  largestNum = num3
```

// check if num2 is largest

elseif num2 > num1 and num2 > num3

```
  largestNum = num2
```

// check if num1 is largest

else

```
  largestNum = num1
```

Function SmallestNumber(integer num1,integer num2,integer num3) returns integer smallestNum

// SmallestNumber function definition with 3 parameters

// check if num3 is smallest

if num3 < num1 and num3 < num2

```
  smallestNum = num3
```

// check if num2 is smallest

elseif num2 < num1 and num2 < num3

```
  smallestNum = num2
```

// check if num1 is smallest

else

```
  smallestNum = num1
```

Function Main() returns nothing

integer n1

integer n2

integer n3

// Input 3 numbers by user

n1 = Get next input

n2 = Get next input

n3 = Get next input

// call function LargestNumber with 3 arguments

Put "largest: " to output

Put LargestNumber(n1, n2, n3) to output

Put "\n" to output

// call function SmallestNumber with 3 arguments

Put "smallest: " to output

Put SmallestNumber(n1, n2, n3) to output